# Подскажите пожалуйста, почему скорость записи на диск HDD сильно проседает?

Tags: администрирование, файловая-система, производительность, диск, скорость

Есть два сервера с ОС Windows. На каждом из них установлен Raid10 массив из 4-х HDD.

1. В первой системе используются 4 диска HGST HUS726T4TALE6L4 : 4000,7 GB
   К ней вопросов вроде как нет, что подтверждают результаты тестирования в CrystalDiskMark8_0_4c

[image: тест первой системы]

2. Во второй системе используются 4 диска 4TB 3.5" Toshiba 7200 rpm SAS 12Gb/s MG08SDA400E
   Я заметил что скорость копирования в эту систему занимает очень много времени, и решил провести такой же тест.

[image: тест второй системы]

Тут видно что скорость записи несоразмерно меньше. И это мне кажется странным, даже в сравнении с первой машиной . В тоже время, обслуживающий вторую машину персонал, утверждает что всё хорошо с дисками, и они исправны. Подскажите пожалуйста как объяснить такие результаты теста? Как мне аргументировать что тут что то не так? Или наоборот всё правильно и я ошибаюсь? А если есть какая то неисправность то как её выяснить? Может есть какой то список причин почему так может быть?

Comment: Это пустые диски или на них есть файловая система и она уже заполнена какими-то файлами?

Comment: на обоих машинах есть файловая система NTFS, на первой машине так же есть множество рабочих файлов, на второй машине пустой диск с NTFS

Comment: Возможно износ диска

Comment: диски на второй машине новые

Comment: Значит сами по себе такие. Скорость такую видел на вд грин.

Comment: как вы считаете это нормально для серверных SAS дисков?

Comment: Сравните размеры секторов всех дисков в raid. Скорость записи может проседать, если в одном массиве имеется разброс размеров, например у трёх дефолтный 512-байт, а у четвёртого 4КБ. Для раид это критично. Установить новые размеры секторов можно при форматировании дисков.

Comment: Ещё глянь прерывания. Если чтото спамит в прерывания — может быть проблема в этом

Comment: К сожалению у меня нет доступа к железу, я с дисками общаюсь изнутри виртуальной машины...

Comment: Проверять не этой прогой надо - её результаты обычно завышены.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

поскольку скорость записи у них в любом случае так себе(что продиктовано конструктивными особенностями), для начала стоит учесть логику этих `современных патифонов`.

у разных моделей, разный объем кэша(ТТХ не редко могут быть указаны и на корпусе самих HDD), да и файлы бывают разного размера, иногда большего чем кэш.

если совсем на пальцах, вариантов логики как минимум пара.

---

первый - файл меньше кэша:

1. кэш проглатывает его целиком, система видит мегаприятную скорость записи, и на этот момент она уже считает что запись окончена(хотя запись грубо говоря даже не началась)
2. из кэша записывается на диск

- 2.1. тут вы уже можете кинуть следующий файл(если он меньше свободного кэша - см пункт 1)

3. запись окончена

---

второй вариант - файл в разы больше кэша:

1. кэш забивается полностью
2. поскольку файл еще не кончился, а кеша уже нет, остальное пишется на сам hdd напрямую, с настоящей скоростью винта.

- 2.1. любые дополнительно брошенные на него файлы, в лучшем случае встанут в очередь, если конечно софт это позволяет.

3. файл только что кончился, но первая часть всё еще в кэше(теперь уже она будет записываться на сам винт).
4. запись окончена

---

разумеется есть еще такие нюансы:

- сначала файл может записываться и в кэш и на сам диск одновременно
- это описание никак не учитывает влияние RAID'ов
- внутри рейда, даже если его лепили не как попало, могут быть винты с разными кэшами, а кэши это по сути та же оперативка. там целый зоопарк вариантов отличающихся друг от друга буквально во всём(ddr2 - gddr7x+)

// какие используются в HDD, не подскажу ибо не интересовался

- как уже говорили - износ, размер кластера,

---

тест в CDM показывает усредненный по всему времени результат. поскольку режимов записи как минимум пара(описал выше), надо смотреть хроноголический график.

в том же `process explorer` есть хронология нагрузки i/o. там можно увидеть: и в какой момент отвалился кэш, и скорость кэша, и реальную скорость HDD(когда кэш уже кончился).

да и ваше замечание на счет `диски новые` не очень однозначно.

сошедшие 5 минут назад с конвейера конечно новые, но и те что за 10лет лежания на полке магазина ни разу не использовались - это тоже новые, а разницы между ними, гхм... не мало

---

я если что "не настоящий железячник" - на истину в последней инстанции не претендую

p.s. ужс... часа 3 ушло чтоб пораскинуть мозгами, осталось собрать их теперь обратно... :3

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ! Тут ещё один момент раскрылся, оказывается админы второго сервера собрали 5-й рейд вместо 10-го, я почитал он на запись медленнее 10-го, так что возможно дело ещё и в этом.

Comment: @ИванК, всегда пожалуйста :3 `5-й рейд ` **`вместо`** `10-го` может быть 5й оказался для них более подходящим, все таки там не только скорость но и функционал от числа к числу устраивает какую то гхм... странную для лишь одного числа, чехарду. `возможно он медленнее` может и так, из рейдов более менее помню только jbod, да и то только по вики)))

Answer (score 0):

У обоих моделей жесткого диска есть параметр, именуемый "скорость передачи данных". Если у HGST она 600 Мб/с, то у Toshiba она 243 Мб/с. Если верить спецификациям в этих ваших инторнетах.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).